# These vectors are linearly independent, yet determinant is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Here are four vectors:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 4 \\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 4 \\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 4 \\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 5 \\0\end{pmatrix}$$

If I input this into wolfram alpha, I get that these are linearly independent. However, when I place these vectors into a matrix and expand by the row of zeros, I get 0 determinant, which suggests they are linearly dependent?!?!?

Comment: What exactly do you “input... into wolfram alpha?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are linearly dependent:
$$4\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 4 \\0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 4 \\0\end{pmatrix}+2 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 4 \\0\end{pmatrix}-4\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 5 \\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 4):

These vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if the last coordinate (=0) is deleted. But in $\mathbb{R}^3$ each set of linearly independent vectors has cardinality $\leq 3$.

Comment: Or, conversely, if they were independent, their span would be $\mathbb R^4$, but obviously $(0,0,0,1)^t$ isn't in that span.

Answer (score 3):

These are not linearly independent, observe the first 3 elements of each vector, to prove linear dependency.

$-1/4$ times the $2$nd vector +$3/2$ times the $3$rd vector, gives you the $4$th vector.